# Using [image,label] = dataset.take(2) returns two tuples instead of a single one

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I have a **TFRecord file** in which i've stored **images wrapped bytes as strings** and the **labels as ints64**. I'm using the code below to manipulate the images and labels:

```py
# Create dataset from TFRecord file 
records_path = DATA_DIR + 'TFRecords/train_0.tfrecords'
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames=records_path)

# Map dataset from parsing function
parsed_dataset = dataset.map(parsing_fn)
print(parsed_dataset)

# Take a testing sample
image,label = parsed_dataset.take(2)
print(image,label)
```

Which outputs:

```
Tensor("ParseSingleExample/ParseSingleExample:1", shape=(), dtype=int64)
<MapDataset shapes: ((None,), ()), types: (tf.float32, tf.int64)>

((<tf.Tensor: id=635, shape=(185256,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([162., 162., 170., ...,  17.,  17., 255.], dtype=float32)>,
  <tf.Tensor: id=636, shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=183350>),
 (<tf.Tensor: id=637, shape=(153120,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([208., 207., 202., ..., 240., 240., 242.], dtype=float32)>,
  <tf.Tensor: id=638, shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=183350>))
```

Which means that **image** and **label** are **tuples containing tensors** that corresponds each to the **image and label** of **two different images**, instead of each one having the respectively image and label data from the **same image**.

image[0] = **image bytes** from **image 1**

image[1] = **label** info from **image 1**

label[0] = **image bytes** from **image 2**

label[1] = **label** info from **image 2**

Does anyone know why using "image = take(1)" returns a *TakeDataset*, instead of a tuple containing only one data sample with the tensors that corresponds to the image bytes and label data?

## Helper fn's

```py
# Data stored format
data = {
    'image': wrap_bytes(img_bytes),
    'label': wrap_int64(label)
}

# Parsing function
def parsing_fn(serialized):

    # Define a dict with the data-names and types we expect to
    # find in the TFRecords file.

    features = \
        {
            'image': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
            'label': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)
        }

    # Parse the serialized data so we get a dict with our data.
    parsed_example = tf.io.parse_single_example(serialized=serialized,
                                             features=features)

    # Get the image as raw bytes.
    image_raw = parsed_example['image']

    # Decode the raw bytes so it becomes a tensor with type.
    image = tf.io.decode_raw(image_raw, tf.uint8)
    
    # The type is now uint8 but we need it to be float.
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)

    # Get the label associated with the image.
    label = parsed_example['label']
    # The image and label are now correct TensorFlow types.
    return image, label
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method take create a dataset. It doesn't extract an element from the dataset. [See documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#take).

If you want to extract an element from the data, you can use:
`tf.compat.v1.data.make_one_shot_iterator()`
I didn't find a cleaner way to extract elements from a dataset.

Example:

```
iterator = tf.compat.v1.data.make_one_shot_iterator(parsed_dataset)
image, label = iterator.get_next()
```